# IndexError: list Index out of Range in a Error about Arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays

this might be a silly question, since I am new to Python 3.4.3, I need some help

```
print("Available slots for Accounts: \n \n 1:",names[0], "\n \n 2:", \
        names[1], "\n \n 3:", names[2], "\n \n 4:", names[3], \
        "\n \n 5:", names[4], "\n \n 6:", names[5], "\n \n 7:", \
        names[6])
```

I have an empty array declared at the top of my program with 6 empty slots. The above code is inside a function as well. The whole array gets saved and loaded into a Pickle file as necessary (if that helps). When the function gets to the above part of the code, however, I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Culminating 2.py", line 281, in Manager
print("Available slots for Accounts: \n \n 1:",names(0), "\n \n 2:", \
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I'm not sure what causes this error. The array is declared like this:

```
names = ["empty","empty","empty","empty","empty","empty", "empty"]
```

The whole function that uses these arrays is right here:

```
def Manager():
global sales_cash
global sales_creditcard
global sales_octopus
global cost_coke
global cost_mint
global cost_sandwich
global stock_sandwich
global stock_mint
global stock_coke
global accounts
global i
global names
global shop_revenue
global i
m_optionselect = input("1: Stock Price \n \n 2: Check inventory" \
            "\n \n 3: Check Sales \n \n 4: Create new account" \
                     "\n \n 5: Buy stock \n \n " \
                     "6: Check Revenue \n \n 7: Quit")
if m_optionselect == "7":
        StartUp()
elif m_optionselect == "3":
    print("Sales by cash: $",sales_cash)
    print("Sales by octopus: $",sales_octopus)
    print("Sales by credit card: $",sales_creditcard)
    Manager()
elif m_optionselect == "2":
        print("Number of sandwiches", stock_sandwich)
        print("Number of cokes", stock_coke)
        print("Number of mint", stock_mint)
        Manager()
elif m_optionselect == "1":
    stock_change = input("Select item to change price: \n \n" \
                "1: Sandwich \n \n 2: Coke \n \n 3:Mint")
    if stock_change == "1":
            sandwich_change = float(input("Enter new price"))
            cost_sandwich = 0 + sandwich_change
            Manager()
    elif stock_change == "2":
            coke_change = float(input("Enter new price"))
            cost_coke = 0 + coke_change
            Manager()
    elif stock_change == "3":
            mint_change = float(input("Enter new price"))
            cost_mint = 0 + mint_change
            Manager()
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
        Manager()
elif m_optionselect == "4":
        print("Available slots for Accounts: \n \n 1:",names[0], "\n \n 2:", \
        names[1], "\n \n 3:", names[2], "\n \n 4:", names[3], \
        "\n \n 5:", names[4], "\n \n 6:", names[5], "\n \n 7:", \
        names[6])
        account_create = input("Which account slot to fill up (1-6): ")
        if account_create == "1":
            names[0] = input("Enter name of account holder")
            accounts[0] = input("Enter password of account holder")
        elif account_create == "2":
            names[1] = input("Enter name of account holder")
            accounts[1] = input("Enter password of account holder")
        elif account_create == "3":
            names[2] = input("Enter name of account holder")
            accounts[2] = input("Enter name of account holder")
        elif account_create == "4":
            names[3] = input("Enter name of account holder")
            accounts[3] = input("Enter name of account holder")
        elif account_create == "5":
            names[4] = input("Enter name of account holder")
            accounts[4] = input("Enter name of account holder")
        elif account_create == "6":
            names[5] = input("Enter name of account holder")
            accounts[5] = input("Enter name of account holder")
        elif account_create == "7":
            names[6] = input("Enter name of account holder")
            accounts[6] = input("Enter name of account holder")
        else:
            print("Invalid input, enter again")
            Manager()
        Manager()
elif m_optionselect == "5":
    add_stock_choice = input("1: Sandwich \n \n 2: Coke \n \n 3: Mint")
    if add_stock_choice == "1" and shop_revenue >= 4:
        add_stock_sandwich = int(input("$4.00/sandwich \n \n Enter amount"))
        stock_sandwich = add_stock_sandwich + stock_sandwich
        shop_revenue = shop_revenue - 4*(add_stock_sandwich)
        Manager()
    elif add_stock_choice == "2" and shop_revenue >= 2.5:
        add_stock_coke = int(input("$2.50/coke \n \n Enter amount"))
        stock_coke = add_stock_coke + stock_coke
        shop_revenue = shop_revenue - 2.5*(add_stock_coke)
        Manager()
    elif add_stock_choice == "3" and shop_revenue >= 5:
        add_stock_mint = int(input("$5.00/mint \n \n Enter amount"))
        stock_mint = add_stock_mint + stock_mint
        shop_revenue = shop_revenue - 5*(add_stock_mint)
        Manager()
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
        Manager()
elif m_optionselect == "6":
    print("The revenue is $",shop_revenue)
    print("Total profit is $",shop_revenue-10000)
    Manager()
else:
    print("Invalid input")
    Manager()
```

Thanks for your consideration. :D

Comment: The code above does not show the error you're saying. Please copy here a MINIMAL example that could reproduce your error. The thing you've posted doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The error message does not match the code you have pasted. It shows you are using `names(0)`, not `names[0]`.

Comment: Umm, I double checked, tried again, and got a little different error message now:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Culminating 2.py", line 284, in Manager
    names[6])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Where exactly are you defining that variable?

Comment: Right at the top, even before functions are defined. Lines 1 and 2, followed by more variables